# How to reorder a dropdown list (jquery)

Tags: jquery, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown box and a textbox (year). When the user enters something on the textbox, the  dropdown box items that startswith(textbox) to be on top.For example, if the user writes (on textbox) 1999, all the listitems that start with 1999 (in alphabetical order) should be on top. 
Is this possible with jquery?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an handler to the change event for the text box that grabs its value, finds all the options that start with that, and remove and prepend them to the beginning of the select list like this:

```
$('#myTextBox').on('change', function(){

    var $select = ;
    var textBoxValue = $(this).val();

    $('#mySelect option').filter(function(){
        return this.innerHTML.indexOf(textBoxValue) == 0;
    })
        .remove()
        .prependTo($('#mySelect'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How can i filter on the text.i.e <option value="d123">300 - 3</option><option value="d321">300 -1</option>. I want to filter on 300 ? I've tried [text^="' + textBoxValue + '"]' with no luck

Comment: @user1750037: I've updated my solution to show how you can do that using jquery's `filter` function

Comment: Not bad! I used $('#select1 option:contains("' + textBoxValue + '")')
which may help other people

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible.. Created the [Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IvKmcAGE76lmCfeUGtPx?p=preview) for your reference..